# Django absolute imports

Tags: python, django, import, module, package

Lets say there is a system wide module named `foobar`, and a django app named `foobar` too, and I cannot edit none of them, because they are external projects.

Now, I would like to use the system foobar module, not the application, but it does not work:

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.3

$ ./manage.py --version
1.3.1

$ ./manage.py shell
>>> import foobar
>>> print (foobar)
<module 'foobar' from '/path/to/myproject/foobar/__init__.pyc'>
```

How can I do ? I suppose I would have `<module 'foobar' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/foobar/__init__.pyc'>` instead.

Comment: Did i understand this correctly - you have installed foreign app by unpacking it into your project folder? Why are you using it by import foobar then, not import myproject.foobar?

Comment: The foobar app is more a submodule. The thing is I just cannot edit it, and I am looking how to import the system module, not the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python looks for packages at the locations defined in the environment variable `PYTHONPATH`. You can modify this from within Python quite easily:

https://docs.python.org/2/install/index.html#modifying-python-s-search-path

You'll want to change `sys.path` so that the directory containing the system foobar module is *before* the application directory.

Assuming your `sys.path` looks like:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

and `foobar` is in both the current working directory (indicated with `''`), and the system `site-packages` directory, you want to get the system `foobar` closer to the front of the list:

```
>>> sys.path.insert(0, '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/foobar')
>>> sys.path
['/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/foobar', 
 '', '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

Note that this change to the path will only apply for the running process/instance of Python (in this case, the interactive session), and later processes will start up with the original path.

#### Solution without modifying the path

If you can't or don't want to modify sys.path, you can use the [`imp`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html) module to manually import a module:

```
import imp

name = 'foobar'
path = '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/foobar'

fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module(name, path)
try:
    imp.load_module(name, fp, pathname, description)
finally:
    # Make sure the file pointer was closed:
    if fp:
        fp.close()
```

#### Solution with modifying the path only temporarily

This solution doesn't need to know where the system `foobar` package is ahead of time, only that you want the one that *isn't* in the current directory:

```
import imp
import sys

# Temporarily remove the current working directory from the path:
cwd = sys.path.pop(0)

# Now we can import the system `foobar`:
import foobar

# Put the current working directory back where it belongs:
sys.path.insert(0, cwd)
```

Comment: I just need to load the system wide foobar in this very case, usually I deal with the foobar application. Plus, changing the whole path may bring side effects I do not control. Don't your solution seem a bit excessive ?

Comment: Also, I used the interactive session just to explain my issue, but I need the solution in a real django app file.

Comment: Your second solution seems satisfying, but the hard path is annoying. It may differ depending on the OS or the python version.

Comment: Fair enough! I added another possible solution that doesn't need a hard coded path.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, no hard code path

```
import os
import sys
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__) 
# make sure the path is right, it depends on where you put the file is

# If PROJECT_DIR in sys.path, remove it and append to the end.
syspath = sys.path
syspath_set = set(syspath)
syspath_set.discard(PROJECT_DIR)
sys.path = list(syspath_set)

sys.path.append(PROJECT_DIR)

# Then try
import foobar

# At last, change it back, prevent other import mistakes
sys.path = syspath
```